# Как сегодня парсить количество комментариев с youtube (без api)?

Tags: парсер, youtube

Youtube API очень часто отдает чушь. Пример, у видео может быть 5 комментов, а API отдает 2000.

Попробовал открыть мобильную версию для видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXpC12uGdg8 (тут 77 комментов на текущую минут), в итоге мобильная версия показывает что комментов 1219 комментов.

Comment: По скорости работы будет быстрей API получить чем всю страницу взять, парсить...

Comment: @Pavel8289 Я же написал, что API чушь отдает периодически

Comment: На странице ютуба показаны только комменты 1-го уровня и их 77. А есть комменты к комментам и так далее :)

Comment: @Visman да, есть вложенные (только заметил), но вложенность только 2х уровневая и у этого видео не у многих комментов есть вложенность и она не более 15 подкомментов, то есть 1219 комментов не может быть

Comment: Советую создать ютуб видео и самому комментировать чтоб уловить правильный подсчет... и поймешь что api от youtube не может глючить, это же ГУГЛ ))